# ReferenceError: Twilio is not defined

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, twilio

I am trying to implement the Twilio Android and IOS [Client SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client) using [this plugin](https://github.com/stevegraham/twilio_client_phonegap). The app is using Cordova, AngularJS and Ionic.

When trying to call the Twilio object within Angular I get the following error:
[ReferenceError: Twilio is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoTwU.png). The Twilio object is used within a controller inside App.js.

I have imported the plugin in HTML:

`<script src="plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.twilioclient\www\tcPlugin.js"></script>`.

If more information is needed please let me know!

Comment: Hvae you tried injecting Twilio is your controller ?

Comment: I got the following error: 'ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TwilioProvider <- Twilio <- phoneCtrl'. I also tried to import another script and that succeeded without having to inject anything.

Comment: But did you tried  injecting in your controller like  this .controller('phoneCtrl', function($scope, Twilio)

Comment: Yes, it returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. I have copied the plugin folder`com.phonegap.plugins.twilioclient` from `../YourApp/plugins` to the `../YourApp/www/lib`.

This has resolved the ReferenceError and I was able to set up a voice call using the Twilio PhoneGap plugin.